# Как передать переменную из одного метода в другой? Java

Tags: java

Есть 2 класса:

```
public class InterpreterMediator1 {
private String intemsg;

public String getInteMSG() {
    return intemsg;
}

public void setIntemsg(String intemsg) {
    this.intemsg = intemsg;
}}
```

И

```
public class InterpreterMediator2 {

private NewJFrame frame;

public InterpreterMediator2(NewJFrame frame) {
    this.frame = frame;
}

public void getStr() {
    InterpreterMediator1 im = new InterpreterMediator1();
    String s = im.getInteMSG();
    frame.setJTextArea1(s);
}}
```

Первый из класса Interpreter принимает какую то строку и передает ее во второй, чтобы тот можно было вызвать в JFrame и засунуть эту строчку в текст арею. Проблема в том, что  InterpreterMediator1 строка приходит корректно, а вот в InterpreterMediator2 я уже получаю null если, например, вывести то, что я получил через System.out. Проблема, видимо, в том что когда я в InterpreterMediator2 пытаюсь показать строку, то она еще пустая, потому и null, но как решить эту проблему я так и не понял. Я пытался ставить там Thread.sleep, но он ждет отведенное время и показывает мне null, хотя строка уже должна была прийти. Как мне в InterpreterMediator2 корректно получить строки?

Весь проект - это интерпретатор Бейсика, к которому я пытаюсь прикрутить ГУИ. Исходный код интерпретатора для меня очень сложный, поэтому делаю тупые костыли в виде классов посредников, которые бы передавали выводимую интерпретатором инфу в JFrame... Если нужно будет, то скину код всего остального.

Answer (score 1):

А что Вы хотели получить, если Вы только-только создали объект `InterpreterMediator1`? Вот так будет работать

```
public void getStr() {
    InterpreterMediator1 im = new InterpreterMediator1();
    im.setIntemsg("test");
    String s = im.getInteMSG();
    frame.setJTextArea1(s);
}
```

Только какой в этом толк? Какую задачу Вы решаете?

Comment: Тут да, ничего не решается. Мне нужно, чтобы та строчка, которая приходила в InterpreterMediator1, там и "задерживалась" на какое то время, а потом я в InterpreterMediator2 ее бы получил и перенаправил в JFrame.

Comment: @Kensi Она там и остается до тех пор пока Вы ее не перезапишите или не уничтожите экземпляр класса InterpreterMediator1

Comment: Т.е. получить ее в другом методе другого класса невозможно?

Comment: @Kensi есть классы, есть объекты. Вы о чем говорите?